# How do I get gesture control working with table views?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I made some table views in storyboard and some arrays to display the data.
I am trying to get the tableview cell to go to a certain push depending on what row it is in:

```
_Locations = @[@"showSignIn",
               @"showSignUp",];
```

For the gestures, I did this:

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int row = [indexPath row];

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:_Locations[row] sender:self];
}
```

But that doesn't seem to work. When I click on any item on the tableview, it always goes to the first one. How do I fix this/ why does it work here, and not here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SplashTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SplashTableViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    int row = [indexPath row];

    cell.OptionLabel.text = _Options[row];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the value of `row`? Did you assign the correct identifiers in the storyboard?

Comment: @Matthias It says row 0 for the first one and row 1 for the second one, so I think that's set up correctly. It's just usually with `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:_Locations[row] sender:self];`  There's an `@""` where the `_Locations[row]` is.

Comment: Check, whether the proper `_Location`, correctly initialized and not changed.

Comment: @Matthias It was, I set it up as strong in my .h file:   `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *Locations;` Also I logged the _Locations[row] and it does showSignIn for the first one and showSignUp for the second one, so it is working. It's just stopping because it is not in `@""` format (I think).